# Append property to each object within array

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Good morning all,

So here I asked myself the question to see if I was optimizing this rating there but I feel like I'm doing the wrong thing.

So let me explain.

We recover an array with objects, example of users.

Who would give this:

```
 [
   {
     'name': 'john',
     'age': '25'
   },
   {
     'name': 'Doe',
     'age': '28'
   },
   ...
 ]
```

But in vuejs or in javascript or other, I find myself sometimes adding an example value: "'edit': false", but here to add it to all my objects in my table I pass the table with an each and i add this value like that. but I don't find it clean would you have another tip or just how do you do it?

```
 [
   {
     'name': 'john',
     'age': '25',
     'edit': false
   },
   {
     'name': 'Doe',
     'age': '28',
     'edit': false
   },
   ...
 ]
```

i do like that personally

```
$.each(this.users, function(key){
                        Vue.set(this, 'edit', false)
                    });
```

Thank you for your answers I wish you a good day and above all good health. Sorry about my bad english!

Comment: seems that it is working fine without any issue, so what's actually you wanted now?

Comment: I'm just trying to find out if there is any other solution than mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ES6, you can do one liner like that:

```
var users = [
    { name: 'John', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 28 }
];

users.map(user => user.edit = false);
```

Comment: Using `map()` this way doesn't make much sense, as it returns useless array of `false`'s and mutates source array. You'd be much better off with `Array.prototype.forEach()`. However, if you attempted to do immutable edit, you may refer to [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60882214/11299053) for proper way to do that.

Comment: For you the most optimized would be what answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use map and spread operator

```
const users = [
    { name: 'John', age: 25 },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 28 }
];

const usersUpdated = users.map(user => ({ ...user, edit: false }));
```